# Hibernate proxy converter for GWT

Tags: java, converting, hibernate, proxy, gwt

Here's a class that converts Hibernate proxies to normal classes. This is useful with GWT for example, when sending objects loaded from database to the GWT client.
Please review it.

```
package ru.minogin.core.server.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSortedSet;
import org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy;
import org.hibernate.proxy.LazyInitializer;

import ru.minogin.core.client.bean.Bean;
import ru.minogin.core.server.reflection.ReflectionUtils;

/**
 * Thread-safety: this class in not thread-safe.
 *
 * @author Andrey Minogin
 * @version 1.0, 02/28/11
 *
 */
public class Dehibernator {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Dehibernator.class);

    private IdentityHashMap<Object, Object> processed;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T clean(T object) {
        processed = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>();

        logger.debug("Cleaning: " + (object != null ? object.getClass() : null));
        return (T) doClean(object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Object doClean(Object dirty) {
        logger.debug("Do clean: " + (dirty != null ? dirty.getClass() : null));

        if (dirty == null)
            return null;

        if (processed.containsKey(dirty)) {
            logger.debug("Object already cleaned, skipping.");

            return processed.get(dirty);
        }

        if (isPrimitive(dirty)) {
            logger.debug("Object is primitive, skipping.");

            return dirty;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof PersistentList) {
            logger.debug("Object is a PersistentList");

            PersistentList dirtyList = (PersistentList) dirty;
            List<Object> cleanList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtyList, cleanList);
            if (dirtyList.wasInitialized()) {
                for (Object value : dirtyList) {
                    cleanList.add(doClean(value));
                }
            }
            return cleanList;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof PersistentBag) {
            logger.debug("Object is a PersistentBag");

            PersistentBag dirtyList = (PersistentBag) dirty;
            List<Object> cleanList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtyList, cleanList);
            if (dirtyList.wasInitialized()) {
                for (Object value : dirtyList) {
                    cleanList.add(doClean(value));
                }
            }
            return cleanList;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof PersistentSortedSet) {
            logger.debug("Object is a PersistentSortedSet");

            PersistentSortedSet dirtySet = (PersistentSortedSet) dirty;
            Set<Object> cleanSet = new TreeSet<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtySet, cleanSet);
            if (dirtySet.wasInitialized()) {
                for (Object value : dirtySet) {
                    cleanSet.add(doClean(value));
                }
            }
            return cleanSet;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof PersistentSet) {
            logger.debug("Object is a PersistentSet");

            PersistentSet dirtySet = (PersistentSet) dirty;
            Set<Object> cleanSet = new HashSet<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtySet, cleanSet);
            if (dirtySet.wasInitialized()) {
                for (Object value : dirtySet) {
                    cleanSet.add(doClean(value));
                }
            }
            return cleanSet;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof PersistentMap) {
            logger.debug("Object is a PersistentMap");

            PersistentMap dirtyMap = (PersistentMap) dirty;
            Map<Object, Object> cleanMap = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            processed.put(dirtyMap, cleanMap);
            if (dirtyMap.wasInitialized()) {
                for (Object key : dirtyMap.keySet()) {
                    Object value = dirtyMap.get(key);
                    cleanMap.put(doClean(key), doClean(value));
                }
            }
            return cleanMap;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof List) {
            logger.debug("Object is a List");

            List<Object> dirtyList = (List<Object>) dirty;
            List<Object> cleanList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtyList, cleanList);
            for (Object value : dirtyList) {
                cleanList.add(doClean(value));
            }
            return cleanList;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
            logger.debug("Object is a LinkedHashMap");

            Map<Object, Object> dirtyMap = (Map<Object, Object>) dirty;
            Map<Object, Object> cleanMap = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            processed.put(dirtyMap, cleanMap);
            for (Object key : dirtyMap.keySet()) {
                Object value = dirtyMap.get(key);
                cleanMap.put(doClean(key), doClean(value));
            }
            return cleanMap;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof HashMap) {
            logger.debug("Object is a HashMap");

            Map<Object, Object> dirtyMap = (Map<Object, Object>) dirty;
            Map<Object, Object> cleanMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
            processed.put(dirtyMap, cleanMap);
            for (Object key : dirtyMap.keySet()) {
                Object value = dirtyMap.get(key);
                cleanMap.put(doClean(key), doClean(value));
            }
            return cleanMap;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof LinkedHashSet<?>) {
            logger.debug("Object is a LinkedHashSet");

            Set<Object> dirtySet = (LinkedHashSet<Object>) dirty;
            Set<Object> cleanSet = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtySet, cleanSet);
            for (Object value : dirtySet) {
                cleanSet.add(doClean(value));
            }
            return cleanSet;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof HashSet<?>) {
            logger.debug("Object is a HashSet");

            Set<Object> dirtySet = (HashSet<Object>) dirty;
            Set<Object> cleanSet = new HashSet<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtySet, cleanSet);
            for (Object value : dirtySet) {
                cleanSet.add(doClean(value));
            }
            return cleanSet;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof TreeSet<?>) {
            logger.debug("Object is a TreeSet");

            Set<Object> dirtySet = (TreeSet<Object>) dirty;
            Set<Object> cleanSet = new TreeSet<Object>();
            processed.put(dirtySet, cleanSet);
            for (Object value : dirtySet) {
                cleanSet.add(doClean(value));
            }
            return cleanSet;
        }

        if (dirty instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            logger.debug("Object is a HibernateProxy");

            HibernateProxy proxy = (HibernateProxy) dirty;
            LazyInitializer lazyInitializer = proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
            if (lazyInitializer.isUninitialized()) {
                logger.debug("It is uninitialized, skipping");

                processed.put(dirty, null);
                return null;
            }
            else {
                logger.debug("It is initialized, getting implementati");

                dirty = lazyInitializer.getImplementation();
            }
        }

        if (dirty instanceof Bean) {
            logger.debug("Object is a Bean");

            Bean bean = (Bean) dirty;
            processed.put(bean, bean);
            for (String property : bean.getPropertyNames()) {
                bean.set(property, doClean(bean.get(property)));
            }
            return bean;
        }

        processed.put(dirty, dirty);
        for (String property : ReflectionUtils.getProperties(dirty)) {
            logger.debug("Processing property " + property);

            Object value = ReflectionUtils.get(dirty, property);
            ReflectionUtils.setIfPossible(dirty, property, doClean(value));
        }
        return dirty;
    }

    private boolean isPrimitive(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof String)
            return true;

        if (object instanceof Date)
            return true;

        if (object instanceof Enum)
            return true;

        Class<? extends Object> xClass = object.getClass();
        if (xClass.isPrimitive())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`doClean()` is crying out for decomposition. Compare

```
if (dirty instanceof PersistentList) {
    logger.debug("Object is a PersistentList");

    PersistentList dirtyList = (PersistentList) dirty;
    List<Object> cleanList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    processed.put(dirtyList, cleanList);
    if (dirtyList.wasInitialized()) {
        for (Object value : dirtyList) {
            cleanList.add(doClean(value));
        }
    }
    return cleanList;
}
```

to

```
if (dirty instanceof List) {
    logger.debug("Object is a List");

    List<Object> dirtyList = (List<Object>) dirty;
    List<Object> cleanList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    processed.put(dirtyList, cleanList);
    for (Object value : dirtyList) {
        cleanList.add(doClean(value));
    }
    return cleanList;
}
```

The differences are

1. The types in the debug messages.
2. The types in the casts.
3. The types of the clean replacements.
4. The check for `PersistentList.wasInitialized()`.

Similar patterns exist for maps, sets, sorted sets, etc. and can all be refactored into new methods, each handling a different collection interface.

```
if (dirty instanceof List) {
    return cleanList((List)dirty);
}

...

private cleanList(List dirty) {
    logger.debug("Object is a List");
    List clean = new ArrayList();
    processed.put(dirty, clean);
    if (shouldCopyValues(dirty)) {
        for (Object value : dirty) {
            clean.add(doClean(value));
        }
    }
    return clean;
}

private shouldCopyValues(Collection dirty) {
    return (!(dirty instanceof Persistent) || ((Persistent)dirty).wasInitialized());
}
```

Note that there's no longer a need for a separate check in `doClean()` for `PersistentList`. One minor optimization here would be to calculate the size of the needed list ahead of time, setting it to zero if it's an uninitialized `PersistentList`.

For the more complicated `Map` and `Set` types, you'll need a way to map from the dirty class to the appropriate clean class. I recommend putting this logic into `cleanSet()` and `cleanMap()` instead of `doClean()`. You could take the same approach as you did above, using a series of `instanceof` tests, or you could use a map.

Actually, only the persistent varieties need to use a different class type, so you may as well just check for those three specifically and otherwise create a new instance of the dirty collection.

Note: when copying values for `Map`s you can use `Map.entrySet()` to get the key/value pairs as `Map.Entry` objects instead of calling `Map.get()` on each key. It's a minor speed improvement.